# Can't load original songs from phone to computer

Tags: sync, music, nokia-lumia-1020

when I bought my lumia 1020 I normally transfered music from computer but its been 3 months and I want to transfer that songs back to my computer but when I connect lumia with usb and open phone file it only shows music which I have downloaded straight into my phone from network. please how make original music appeared in lumia file when I connect it with my Pc

Comment: As far as I know you can't.

Comment: If you did a file transfer to the phone, then the file should still be there, Did you look through all the folders in the USB mapped drive?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods, I would like you to check each of these once:

Firstly, are the songs in the memory card or phone memory? If they are in the memory card, go to the memory_card_drive/Music. You might find it there.

Secondly, If you're not able to locate in the music folder of memory card or phone memory, try other folders. You might have saved it in a different folder.

Thirdly, if you still can't find it, extract the media from the phone using WinAmp software. It automatically asks for media extraction when you plug in the phone.

Fourthly, check for folder permissions and View settings to see of you have hidden any folders by mistake.

Fifthly, if any of the above don't work, maybe there is a compatibility issue with the PC. Install the app [Files](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/files-app-windows-phone-81) and browse all the locations once again.

Let me know if this works for you.